# Simple Java Code (Creating a shopping list in netbeans)

Tags: java, arrays, do-while

Im just creating a simple shopping list using Java in Netbeans. Im having some trouble with the Array Lists and Do While Loops. Does anyone know how to add values (prices) to all the items in my list and also how to make a do while loop which will ask the customer to choose which items to add to a basket which will then print out the entire value to be paid. Thanks Below is the array list i've created.

```
ArrayList<String> ShoppingList = new ArrayList<>();
    ShoppingList.add("Macbook Pro");
    ShoppingList.add("Macbook Air");
    ShoppingList.add("Paracetamol");
    ShoppingList.add("Beer");
    ShoppingList.add("Books");
    ShoppingList.add("Pen");
    ShoppingList.add("Notepads");
    System.out.println(ShoppingList);

    System.out.println(userName+" Our University shop has an offer of the following items" + ShoppingList);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: There are no loops, do-while or otherwise, in the code you've posted. Also, the items in your list are just strings.  What do you mean when you say you want to add prices to them?

Comment: I need to create something similar to shop and i got confused. Is there a way to make a list of items which will have their name and value(in currency).

Comment: Sure, make a class that holds the data you want, then make a list of that type.

Comment: What you mean ? sorry im pretty new to Java

Comment: @HashTagG https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html. Read the tutorial I linked to. It explains what classes and objects are, and how to write them. This is fundamental stuff. Your book must cover that.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are just getting started, this may help:

Create a new class called ShoppingListItem that includes a name and a value

```
public class ShoppingListItem
{
    private String name;
    private long priceInCents;

    public ShoppingListItem( String name, long priceInCents )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.priceInCents = priceInCents;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName( String name )
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public long getPriceInCents()
    {
        return priceInCents;
    }
    public void setPriceInCents( long priceInCents )
    {
        this.priceInCents = priceInCents;
    }
}
```

Then your list would look like this:

```
ArrayList<ShoppingListItem> shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();
shoppingList.add( new ShoppingListItem( "Macbook Pro", 100000L ) );
// ... add additional here
```

Then you can do something like this

```
    long cartValueInCents = shoppingList.stream().mapToLong( item -> item.getPriceInCents() ).sum();
```

Remember the prices are in cents so you'll need to display correctly.  Cents are often used in the real world for currency value rather than floats or doubles.